# Positioning div over a table in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, position, css-position

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.wrapper').append('<div class="floater" />');
            var floater = $('.floater')
            floater.css('top', 100);
            floater.css('left', 200);
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper
        {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            position: relative;
        }

        .floater
        {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            background-color: blue;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="wrapper">
        <tr>
            <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Jsfiddle here (does not work on IE8): http://jsfiddle.net/W5ceN/3/

The idea is to have a div that will be positioned above the table and reposition it with javascript. It works nicely on Firefox and Chrome, but the floating div is not visible in IE8. Probably it's some CSS issue, but I have no idea where to look. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try `z-index` ?

Comment: Yes. Does not help (I tried z-index 9 for table, 99 for table td and 999 for div.floater)

Comment: why the hell do you append a div to a table body? make a surrounding div that works as a container, you are creating invalid dom at the moment `$('.wrapper').append('<div class="floater" />');` adds div to a <table> container ...

Comment: @x4rf41: I tried that too, but it didn't change anything, so I kept it this way

Comment: it will work with proper use of z-index, im 100% sure, z-index works without a problem in IE8. also: always declare a doctype and set the ie meta tag, or else you might be using quirks mode (and thats death to all html)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2KpQ2/. I do not have access to IE8 right now... Does this work? I believe there is an issue adding a div into a table in IE.

Comment: @ryan0319: jsfiddle is incompatible with IE8, so I cannot check. But you basically made a div wrapper around the table. I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: declare a doctype. im pretty sure you are making ie use quirks mode

Comment: Also it might be that append is not functioning in IE8 properly